# WPF: Resource Dictionary x:Name and x:Key

Tags: wpf

In **Resource Dictionary**, can we both have `x:Name` and `x:Key`?

Can we retrieve a self-defined element through `x:Name` instead of `x:key`?

If I wanna store more self-defined attributes in one element, where should I put those attributes?

Comment: @dongx Datacontext works out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No cannot use both **x:key** and **x:name** in resource dictionary.

**FindResource** only works for x:key.

Use can use **Datacontext** for more attributes.